# Understanding a small c# code snippet involving paint()

Tags: c#, visual-studio, graphics

I am new to c#(using visual c# 2010), and was tying to make a simple game, it will have bouncing ball type thing,

I used graphics fillellipse to make a  ball, now i have this code with me,

```
protected override void OnPaint( PaintEventArgs e)
{
    //System.Drawing.Graphics gobj;
    gobj = this.CreateGraphics();
    Pen pen = new Pen(System.Drawing.Color.LightSkyBlue, 6);
    SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Magenta);
    Rectangle myRectangle = new Rectangle((PointToClient(Cursor.Position).X), PointToClient(Cursor.Position).Y, 250, 200);

    gobj.DrawRectangle(pen, myRectangle);
    gobj.FillEllipse(brush, myRectangle);
}
```

when i run this code, i keep on getting many circles and rectangles, popping under a section of screen only, but shouldn't it draw just a  single circle??

Please help me understand this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You drawing rectangle with DrawRectangle method and then circle with FillEllipse, you need to use just FillEllipse. And like Mikant mentioned you don't need to create graphics - use e.Graphics. Here is code:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Magenta);
    e.Graphics.FillEllipse(brush, (this.Height / 2) - 40, (this.Width / 2) - 40, 80, 80);
}
```

This draws circle in form centre.

Good luck in experimenting and learning!

Comment: this might sound like very stupid ques, but is there a difference b/w OnPaint and Form1_Paint ??

Comment: Also i need to constantly update the circle position, shall i go with invalidate method for this?

Comment: [Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/99f6b314-eff7-4adc-bee6-c70d8a736af4/) is the answer about differences between event and method. You can use Invalidate or Refresh. The only difference is whether this happens synchronously or async. Invalidate redraws the contol but does not happen immediatly. Refresh forces an immediate redraw of the control (and its children).

Comment: Any idea on why the code above keeps on popping many circles n rectangles??

Comment: @TarunG: As I mentioned DrawRectangle() draws rectangle(which you can see) and when you use CreateGraphics() it creates lets say layer on your form(thats why you can see many layers with rectangles and circles), but you need to redraw allways on main layer which you can access sing e.Graphics

Answer (score 2):

This should really be a comment, but I don't have high enough privilege yet!

I would get into the good habit of using the [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) when dealing withtypes that use unmanaged resources such as Pen and Font.  It will ensure the correct use of IDisposable objects.

Answer (score 1):

just remember never to use `CreateGraphics` method (especially inside OnPaint). replace all of your `gobj` with `e.Graphics` and enjoy

Comment: this might sound like very stupid ques, but is there a difference b/w OnPaint and Form1_Paint ??

Comment: @TarunG `Form1.Paint += Form1_Paint;` - is a common .NET event driven development style. it is useful when you want to handle events in different program modules, to perform flexible and up-to-date interaction between them. `override void OnPaint(...)` - is an OOP approach: you can statically change bahavior of derived classes via this mechanism. i strongly recommend to use the second approach whenever it's possible. the real practical difference between them now is that even if you write tons of `Paint += ...`, you can simply make them useless with commenting `//base.OnPaint(e);`=)

Comment: okk, thank you for the above explanation, I had this Onpaint for the circle, its working perfect, but now i wish to make another method for creating lines, like a noob i tried creating a second Onpaint1 method, but from where to take the argument e, when i call the function ??

Comment: @TatunG: do all the painting inside `onpaint` method you can create several other methods which would for example draw lines and circles and call them from `OnPaint`. of course `e.Graphics` must be passed to them as a parameter